# Does Ubuntu have problems with identifying two monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors

Ubuntu 16.04

I have no problems with just using two monitors. Everything works as it should, except by identifying the monitors as separated screens. I mean, any program I use that need to identify my screen property, like screen sharing at Google Hangouts, Discord, identifies both monitors like it was a super large single monitor.

The only program where this problem wasn't seen was TopTracker screen capture. But it still just capture a small part of the secondary screen.

Is there something I could do to solve this problem?

Comment: No?Heck, I have a 4 monitor setup myself ;)

Comment: Your mileage may vary, (especially depending on your video card) but I have not had problems with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, about 2 years later...

This was a bug on Chromium webdriver, which was fixed at v83.
No more problems on Google Hangouts, Jist, and others that are based on this driver.

More details at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=437507

Comment: Answering your own question after two years is definitely worth a vote.